# VBA select pivot table by Activecell

Tags: vba, excel

In my excel sheet, the pivot table is copied from another file every month, therefore the name will change every time when a new pivot table is copied to my worksheet. I want to use macro to set the pivot table filter but don't know how to refer the table without knowing the name. I use the code below, it sometimes work, but sometimes would come with error. Could you please take a look if there is any error in my code? or if there is another solution for my situation?

Another problem is, my code adjust two pivot tables in two worksheet, however, the code sometimes (most of the time) end up working on only one sheet. Does any body know the reason?

```
Sub getdeb()
Dim irfile As String
Dim ws1 As Worksheet
Dim ws2 As Worksheet
Dim ws3 As Worksheet
Dim ws4 As Worksheet

With Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFilePicker)
    .AllowMultiSelect = False
    .Title = "Please select a file"
    .ButtonName = "Select"
    .InitialFileName = "C:\"
    If .Show = -1 Then
        irfile = .SelectedItems(1)

        Set wbtarget = ThisWorkbook
        Set wbsource = Workbooks.Open(irfile)

        Set ws1 = wbsource.Sheets("NN Re inzake ART Non-Life")

        Set ws2 = wbsource.Sheets("NN Re inzake ART Life")

        ws2.Cells.Copy Destination:=wbtarget.Sheets("Life").Range("A1")

        ws1.Cells.Copy Destination:=wbtarget.Sheets("NonLife").Range("A1")

        wbsource.Close

        Else
            MsgBox "No file was selected"

    End If
End With

With ThisWorkbook

Set ws3 = Sheets("Life")
Set ws4 = Sheets("NonLife")
ws3.Cells.Clear
ws4.Cells.Clear

End With

With ws3

    With ActiveCell.PivotTable.PivotFields("GAUDI rubriek")
    .PivotItems("A_INT_RENTS_ACCR    ").Visible = False
    .PivotItems("A_OTH_ACCR_ASSETS   ").Visible = False
    .PivotItems("L_COST_PAYABLE      ").Visible = False
    .PivotItems("L_CRED_DIR          ").Visible = False
    .PivotItems("L_CRED_OTH_3P       ").Visible = False
    .PivotItems("L_CRED_OTH_IC       ").Visible = False
    .PivotItems("L_CRED_REINS_IC     ").Visible = False
    .PivotItems("L_DEF_TAX_LIAB      ").Visible = False
    .PivotItems("L_INCOME_TAX        ").Visible = False
    .PivotItems("L_INT_RENTS_ACCR    ").Visible = False
    .PivotItems("L_OTH_PROV          ").Visible = False
    .PivotItems("A_TAX_REC           ").Visible = False
    .PivotItems("L_CRED_REINS_3P     ").Visible = False
    End With

    With ActiveCell.PivotTable.PivotFields("Issuer")
    .ClearAllFilters
    .EnableMultiplePageItems = True
    .PivotItems(" ").Visible = False
    End With

    .Range("N9") = "GRID Mapping DvS"
    .Range("O9") = "GRID Name Mapping DvS"
    .Range("P9") = "Country Mapping DvS"
    .Range("Q9") = "Instrument ID DvS added"
    .Range("R9") = "Country Mapping DvS2"
    .Range("R9") = "Thomson-Reuters id"
    .Range("Q10") = "=$B10&"" ""&$A10"
    .Range("N10:R100").FillDown

End With

With ws4

    With ActiveCell.PivotTable.PivotFields("GAUDI rubriek")
    .PivotItems("A_INT_RENTS_ACCR    ").Visible = False
    .PivotItems("A_OTH_ACCR_ASSETS   ").Visible = False
    .PivotItems("L_COST_PAYABLE      ").Visible = False
    .PivotItems("L_CRED_DIR          ").Visible = False
    .PivotItems("L_CRED_OTH_3P       ").Visible = False
    .PivotItems("L_CRED_OTH_IC       ").Visible = False
    .PivotItems("L_CRED_REINS_IC     ").Visible = False
    .PivotItems("L_DEF_TAX_LIAB      ").Visible = False
    .PivotItems("L_INCOME_TAX        ").Visible = False
    .PivotItems("L_INT_RENTS_ACCR    ").Visible = False
    .PivotItems("L_OTH_PROV          ").Visible = False
    .PivotItems("A_TAX_REC           ").Visible = False
    .PivotItems("L_CRED_REINS_3P     ").Visible = False
    End With

    With ActiveCell.PivotTable.PivotFields("Issuer")
    .ClearAllFilters
    .EnableMultiplePageItems = True
    .PivotItems(" ").Visible = False
    End With

    .Range("N9") = "GRID Mapping DvS"
    .Range("O9") = "GRID Name Mapping DvS"
    .Range("P9") = "Country Mapping DvS"
    .Range("Q9") = "Instrument ID DvS added"
    .Range("R9") = "Country Mapping DvS2"
    .Range("R9") = "Thomson-Reuters id"
    .Range("N10:R500").FillDown
    .Calculate

End With
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

In order to refer to a pivot table and pivot field, it should exist. This part of the code deletes all pivot tables on `ws3`, thus it cannot be referred further:

```
ws3.Cells.Clear
With ws3
    With ActiveCell.PivotTable.PivotFields("GAUDI rubriek")
```

Try to amend your code to this:

```
With ws3.Range(ActiveCell.Address).PivotTable.PivotFields("GAUDI rubriek")
```

everywhere for both `ws3` and `ws4`. Thus you would be referring the relevant `ActiveCell` address on the relevant worksheet.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't show the full code, otherwise its too long. Actually both worksheets are assigned to my one of my worksheet. I will put my full code in.

Comment: Please see my updated code. It's still not the full code. But I Set the ws3 and ws4 as one of my worksheet

Comment: @Gong - writing a [mcve] may seem trivial, but it is really a best practice. I have updated the answer.

Comment: I used your code, it show the same message: Run-time error "1004": Unable to get the PivotTable Property of the Range class

Comment: The code will stop at this line:  With ws3.Range(ActiveCell.Address).PivotTable.PivotFields("GAUDI rubriek")

Comment: @Gong - is there a pivot table with a corresponding field in `ws3`?

Comment: Yes, there is. this is what my other codes do. I printed my code in the question.

Comment: @Gong - There is no PivotTable on `ws3`, because `ws3.Cells.Clear` deletes it.

Comment: Yes, indeed, but following two line copied two new pitot table to the sheets.          
      `ws2.Cells.Copy Destination:=wbtarget.Sheets("Life").Range("A1")`

      `ws1.Cells.Copy Destination:=wbtarget.Sheets("NonLife").Range("A1")`